# Does FileZilla have something like SmartFTP's URL favorites feature?

Tags: filezilla

I really like SmartFTP's feature that allows you to set the actual HTTP path for calling a file from the FTP; you do this by going to "favorites" and entering custom URL mapping.

Does anyone know if FileZilla has this feature? I've checked (also checked Cyberduck), but can't figure out how to do it.

So, when I right-click on an image, for example, to get a link to embed it in html, the 'copy url link' isn't actually a usable image link; I need the HTTP link. With SmartFTP, I can set the domain and path to automatically generate usable http links; I can't figure out how to do this with FileZilla. (I can manually create the links, but with hundreds of files to insert, the automatic link feature would really save time.)

Comment: Not sure why I kept getting downvoted; tried to clarify. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Native Support

**FileZilla**

[Unfortunately, FileZilla does not appear to natively support this feature](https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=32283). It has been requested before and the response seems to be that there are no known plans to add this kind of support.

**Cyberduck**

Regarding [Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io/?l=en), it has the ability to alter portions of the FTP URL to make an HTTP URL but this could not be customized as far as I could tell.

**WinSCP**

One option that seems to at least partially conform to your criteria is [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php), which uses a [PowerShell extension](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/extension_generate_http_url) to perform the conversion. This extension is currently included by default when using the installer.

The command to convert the URL is available by right-clicking the remote file and selecting *File Custom Commands → Generate HTTP URL*. For clarity, the settings can be changed under *Preferences → Commands → Generate HTTP URL → Configure*.

The extension was [improved](https://winscp.net/tracker/1567) recently (in WinSCP 5.11.3) to perform better for a large number of selected files.

---

#### FileZilla and Notepad++

While just a suggestion, an option I might consider would be to use [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) in conjunction with FileZilla.

FileZilla can easily copy hundreds of FTP URLs in a directory to the clipboard -- simply select the first item normally then *Shift + Left-Click* the final item, right-click the selection and choose *Copy URL(s) to clipboard*. These copied FTP URLs can then be easily pasted into Notepad++ for further modification.

In particular, Notepad++ supports [regular expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) in its replacement functions including grouping by parentheses e.g.:

*ex. Grouping By Parentheses*
[image: Grouping By Parentheses]

In this case, $2 corresponds to the second set of parentheses in the find field e.g. `(example.com)`. Note that the example above is probably pretty useless as-is (you could just do a replacement with http://example.com/pictures) but something like it could be useful as a base pattern for other replacements.

This suggestion isn't perfect -- depending on the URL, there is a chance you may have to escape some items. Likewise, it isn't true masking in that you would have to define replacements for each site (and possibly more than one directory).

However, Notepad++ supports macros. This means you could simply perform a replacement for a site once, recording it as a macro, and have it available again for that site with a simple selection from the Notepad++ Macro menu.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think I wasn't totally clear (I edited the question) - I'm trying to create http links to images stored on a CDN, accessed via HTTP; not trying to get to a specific spot when I access the FTP, via a bookmark.

Comment: Just to confirm - you are a) connecting to a ftp server on a CDN and b) using Filezilla's option to copy URLs, is that correct? That is, you end with a link like e.g. `ftp://anon@example.com:21/dir/file.jpg`? And you would like the link to be e.g. `http://example.com/pix/file.jpg`?

Comment: Yes, exactly right.

Comment: Updated my answer. In short, FileZilla doesn't support this currently and Cyberduck's HTTP URL function doesn't seem editable. That said, you could copy the links in bulk from FileZilla and use a program such as Notepad++ (free) to edit them in quantity fairly easily (this is the way I would lean). I did find that WinSCP has (roughly) something like the functionality you are looking for but the actual operations performed poorly with a large quantity of files on my system (though it may still be worth a go on your end).

Comment: Your bad experience with the WinSCP extension on large amount of files should get fixed as a side effect of this change: https://winscp.net/tracker/show_bug.cgi?id=1567 The change will be included in the next WinSCP release. But you can actually install the [new version of the extension](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/extension_generate_http_url) even to the current release to test it.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Awesome. Appreciate the update. =)

Comment: Wow, completely answers my question, and super educational! Thanks so much!

Comment: @Andrew Glad to help. =)